# Using MediaStore in Android studio to limit the number of songs in a playlist

Tags: java, android-studio, mediastore, android-music-player

I'm an absolute beginner in Java and Android Studio and I am trying to edit an open source music player using Android Studio.
The app is currently creating a "last added" playlist and sorting the songs by date using MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED
Is there a way to limit the number of songs in this playlist ?

I hope this description is precise enough..

Thank you :)

Comment: it has nothing to do with Mediastore really, more with the code that actually adds to a given playlist. If you post that part then people will be able to help

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `Limit` in sortOrder parameter of `contentResolver` query.

```
 String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC LIMIT 1";
 Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, sortOrder);
```

GGK

Comment: You saved me an hour two, thanks :)